# can I install anaconda on nginx docker image?

Tags: python, docker, nginx, installation, anaconda

I'm new to docker and I should do face detection project base on nginx and mongoDB docker image.
I don't want change my images because I think on this nginx and mongoDB have some special setup.

to run my code I need anaconda because I can't install some library like dlib with pip.
**my question is, can I install anaconda on nginx docker image or not?if so how?**

thanks

Comment: You'd generally run your Python application in a separate container.  It will be easier to manage if you can use the native Python packaging tools so your Dockerfile can `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`, without involving Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker image for Nginx is based on Debian, so yes, it'll definitely be possible to install `anaconda` in it. However, that's probably not such a good idea, also seeing as the philosophy within Docker is that each Docker container should only have one concern, for which a good rule of thumb is that the container should only be running one process (see [Dockerfile best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#decouple-applications)). You're not meant to run both Nginx, MongoDB as well as your Python code in the same Docker container.

Instead, you probably want to look into [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), it will help you orchestrate running multiple containers. In a `docker-compose.yml` file you can define three 'services', as they are called in `docker-compose` terminology:

- a `mongodb` container exposing port 27017
- a Docker image of your Python face detection project (you'll have to write your own Dockerfile for this), exposing whatever ports are necessary for your application.
- an `nginx` container, probably binding ports 80 & 443 to your host.

You can then set up each service to connect to each other. `docker-compose` also handles Docker networking for you, so you'll be able to access port 27017 on your MongoDB container from your Nginx container as `mongodb:27017` (provided that the service is named 'mongodb')